# How to use ssim in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I looked for where is the correct place in ffmpeg command to put the `-ssim`, or private options. I didn't find it but I got one option working and would share with you. It's working but I don't know why.

First try without ssim and working:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

I tried to put ssim like below and did not working:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq -ssim video.m4v
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -ssim -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -sameq video.m4v
```

And here it works:

```
ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 -g 12 -bf 2 -ssim -sameq video.m4v
```

Someone have any idea why it worked in the last case and not in commands 2 and 3?

Comment: Instead of mentioning that it is "not working" you should provide the complete console outputs associated with each command. Also, [`-sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and has been removed from ffmpeg. For the encoder `mpeg4` you should use `-qscale:v` instead. 2-5 is probably a sane range.

Comment: When I spend time on a problem I really appreciate feedback. Does answer and comment help you ?

Comment: -sameq is still used. You're right about not means "same quality" but same quantization matriz. If you put -sameq you'll have less  spacial compression.

Comment: LordNeck thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -ssim option is relative to the codec (x264) you use.

At least it could explain why your case (3) doesn't work, because you put the option before the -vcodec

Remember that ffmpeg option are not really position independent.
And as far as I remember ssim is part of the AVCodecContext option and should be place after fflag2 like below but it can be wrong as depending of the ffmpeg version you use.

```
 ffmpeg -i input ... codec .... -ssim output
```

Comment: Do you have any source of this ?

Comment: @roberutsu , As I said I was not completely sure of that but after some "googling" I found the following page where the ssim option is clearly dependent of a -flags2 http://avanti.arrozcru.com/tpl_upd.htm